# What is the best way to display List items on the console based on the value of the items' properties?

Tags: c#, list, properties, console, items

I have a List that cointains some objects that have 2 string  and 2 int properties. I would like to be able to display all the 4 properties of an object based on the content of its first property.
For example:  I want to display all the data of all the items of the list that's first property is "Mozart".
Thanks in advance!

I have a really basic class that has 4 properties, 2 strings, and 2 ints, all of them have their respective getters/ setters set to public.

I also have a List that contains some of these objects.

My code looks like this.

```
Console.WriteLine("Give in the name you want to search for!");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
```

After this, I would like to check if the first property is "s", and if it is, display all of that given object's data on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried something already? Using loops (`foreach`) and conditional operators (`if`) might actually come in handy.

Comment: I didn't try anything yet, I'm fairly new to Lists, so I don't really know where ot start with them.

Comment: You can start by reading about them in the documentation then trying some code to solve the issue you are having and finally if you are unable to do so show your progress so far here so that we can help.

Comment: I tried foreach but I wasn't able to reach the property of the objects I tried to shuffle through.

Comment: One way is in your object, override the ToString method to give you a string in the proper format, then just foreach through the collection and print out the object.ToString. Without seeing your object code though we can't recommend a lot of other options as your properties/fields may be private. Give your code and an example of what you want on the screen.

Comment: Okay I will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this and let me know if you're stuck with any of it :)

```
void Main()
{
    List<Music> myMusic = new List<Music>
    {
        new Music 
        { 
            Artist = "Mozart", 
            Album = "Mozarts amazing album", 
            TotalTracks = int.MaxValue, 
            Etc = int.MinValue
        },
        new Music 
        { 
            Artist = "Foo", 
            Album = "Bar", 
            TotalTracks = int.MaxValue, 
            Etc = int.MinValue
        },
    };


    var mozartsMusic = myMusic.Where(music => music.Artist == "Mozart")
                              .ToList();

    mozartsMusic.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

}

public class Music
{
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public int TotalTracks { get; set; }
    public int Etc { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join("\n",this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p=>string.Format("{0} {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(this))));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works too, my mistake was that I tried to use obj instead of var in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
class Datum
{
    public string Composer { get; set; }

    ///wharever other proerties you need

    public string DisplayOutput()
    {
        return this.Composer //+ however you want it displayed
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Datum> data = new List<Datum>();

        foreach (var outputLine in data.Where(d => d.Composer == "Mozart").Select(d=>d.DisplayOutput())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(outputLine);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be a possible way to do so:

```
class Composer
{
   public Composer( string lastName, string firstName, int year, int month )
   {
      LastName = lastName;
      FirstName = firstName;
      YearOfBirth = year;
      MonthOfBirth = month;
   }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public int YearOfBirth { get; set; }
   public int MonthOfBirth { get; set; }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return string.Format( "{0} {1} {2} {3}", LastName, FirstName, YearOfBirth.ToString(), MonthOfBirth.ToString() );
   }
}


class Program
{
   private static new List<Composer> composerList = new List<Composer>();

   static void Main( string[] args )
   {
      composerList.Add( new Composer( "Mozart", "Wolfgang", 1756, 1 ) );
      composerList.Add( new Composer( "Vivaldi", "Antonio", 1678, 3 ) );

      Console.WriteLine( "Please enter a name you want to search for!" );
      string name = Console.ReadLine();
      ShowComposerData( name );
   }


   private static void ShowComposerData( string name )
   {
      foreach( Composer comp in composerList )
      {
         if( comp.LastName == name )
         {
            Console.WriteLine( comp.ToString() );
         }
      }
   }
}
```